# Removing the selected ng-option for next selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have a scenario where i'm able to choose a option from dropdown. Once i have chosen one option that option wont be available for next selection.

Here is my scenario. I have an arraylike below

```
$scope.set = [
    {name:"name1"},
    {name:"name2"},
    {name:"name3"}
];
```

and i'm populating options as below

```
 <select ng-options="opt.name as opt.name for opt in set" data-ng-model="option.name">
 </select>
```

if i select name1 as my first option and after that name1 won't be available for next selection.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mohanguntaka/js25x0q9/) is the fiddle

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a same dropdown or options wouldn't available in other dropdown?

Comment: I am  not clear about your requirement, according to my understanding, when you will select name1 from first drop down then after clicking on add in next drop down you want only two option name2 and name3 and again if you select name3 from second drop down then on next add more you will get only name2 in drop down for selection. Am i right ? please confirm

Comment: @naCheex It is other dropdown but same options model ($scope.set). See my fiddle you can understand better. upon clicking on a button im creating another dropdown with same options.

Comment: yes @AnamikaShrivastava that's right

Comment: confusion is why you  are using dropdown to just label a field?

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/js25x0q9/14/) is the new fiddle

Comment: @naCheex I have to assign a value for each option. if you saw my fiddle i'm using one  input box to capture the value for each option. If i set value for name1 then after,  name1 won't be available to set another value.[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/js25x0q9/16/)

Comment: Can anybody help me in this please?